# Calculating visit to visit variability in R

Tags: r

I am computing visit to visit variability. This statistic is traditionally computed with blood pressure measurements as patients are divided in quantiles of standard deviation of the blood pressure statistic (ex. mean arterial pressure [MAP]). Given that standard deviation is a single statistic, I need to understand how to compute its quartiles in order to calculate visit to visit variability (https://www.jhltonline.org/article/S1053-2498(18)31737-6/pdf).

I am trying out the code with a predictor like mpg from mtcars dataset.

I can compute its standard deviation with the sd function but am not sure how to compute quartiles of the sd in R. Would appreciate all help with this issue.

```
summary(sd(mtcars$mpg)) # returns the same value for each quantile. I would like to see different values for the quantiles.
```

Comment: Maybe `?quantile`

Comment: `summary(sd(mtcars$mpg))`

Comment: quantile of standard deviation (i.e. quartile(sd(mtcars$mpg)) returns a single value). I am interested in seeing all the quartiles in the range (at 0.25...0.95).